# .htaccess rule appending index.php instead of URI

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

My .htaccess looks like this..

```
Options -Indexes

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.domain.com/members/invite/$1 [R,L]

</IfModule>
```

I want to be able to redirect an URL that looks like this..

```
https://sub.domain.com/ZTHF76
```

to...

```
https://www.domain.com/members/invite/ZTHF76
```

But instead I am getting

```
https://www.domain.com/members/invite/index.php
```

I need to keep the first rule to remove `index.php` from the URI of the rest of the application.

Any help with this greatly appreciated.

Comment: @anubhava - nice one that was sending me crazy. Add as an answer if you want I will accept it. Worked like a charm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should reorder your rules and keep redirect rule before rewrite one:

```
Options -Indexes
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.domain.com/members/invite/$1 [L,R=302]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```